# What is the difference between JSXTransform and Babel?

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I have a react project, and I'm currently using `<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>` to transcompile my JSX files. I understand that JSX has been depreciated and that it's suggested I move to babel.

What is the difference between JSX and babel?

How do I transition to babel?

I'm using griddle.io to make tables, will switching from JSX to babel effect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big difference between JSXTransform and Babel is ES2015. You can read more here 
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html

If you don't have warnings in your current code transition will be smooth.

In this doc you can find how to start https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html